# Error: Could not load source layer for INPUT using processing

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing

I am trying to run a process script in QGIS 3.16.11. I need to run `qgis:distancetonearesthubpoints` over selected features from a vector layer created in the script, I use `QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition` method to create an input with the selected features but it throws me an error: `Could not load source layer for INPUT: ...`

The script is the following:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        cargas = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT_CARGAS,
            context
        )
        
        postes = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT_POSTES,
            context
        )

        req = QgsFeatureRequest()
        req.setSubsetOfAttributes(parameters[self.INPUT_CAMPOS_CARGAS],cargas.fields())

        cargas_v2 = cargas.materialize(req, feedback=feedback)
        cargas_v2.selectByExpression(f'"{parameters[self.INPUT_POSTE_ID]}" IS NOT NULL')

        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        req = QgsFeatureRequest()
        postes_v2 = postes.materialize(req, feedback=feedback)

        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        postes_v2.selectByExpression('"tipo" = 1')

        cargas_source = QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(
            cargas_v2.id(), 
            selectedFeaturesOnly=True,
            featureLimit=-1, 
            geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid
        )
        
        postes_source = QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(
            postes_v2.id(),
            selectedFeaturesOnly=True,
            featureLimit=-1,
            geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid
        )
        cargas_aereas = processing.run("qgis:distancetonearesthubpoints",
            {
                'INPUT' : cargas_source,
                #'INPUT': cargas_v2,
                'HUBS'  : postes_source,
                #'HUBS': postes_v2,
                'FIELD' :'dev_id',
                'UNIT'  :0,
                'OUTPUT': parameters['OUTPUT']
            },
            is_child_algorithm=True,
            context=context,
            feedback=feedback
            
        )
        return {self.OUTPUT: cargas_aereas['OUTPUT']}
```

I tried changing `cargas_v2.id()` to `cargas_v2.id().dataProvider().uri().uri()` and `cargas_v2.source()` but the result is the same.

Comment: A question for you: could you filter the response of the `materialize()` call, setting an expression (namely, `f'"{parameters[self.INPUT_POSTE_ID]}" IS NOT NULL'`) in your `QgsFeatureRequest`? In that way you get already the features you need, avoid the `selectByExpression()` call and can pass the whole layer (with no `QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition`) to the `"qgis:distancetonearesthubpoints"` algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i tried and it works!, but i need to do the process twice (with two filter expressions) and i want to avoid writing the whole process twice (and using `materialize` 4 times instead of 2 using `QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition`)